# Change Place Order button

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I got an offline payment method and want to change the "Place Order" button to "Place Free Order" when the price is 0.

The button is created in checkmo.htm, however I can't use JS or PHP here.
I am thankful for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has the same problem.
When the price is 0, this will be called:

> /magento/vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/free.html

You simply need to override this and change your text. Good Luck!